# Uniqueness of Lebesgue-Stieltjes-Measure

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

Let $\mu$ be a finite measure on $(\mathbb R, \mathcal B(\mathbb R))$ and let $F_{\mu}: \mathbb R \rightarrow [0, \infty)$, $F_{\mu}(x) := \mu((- \infty, x])$.

If $F: \mathbb R \rightarrow [0, \infty)$ is bounded, monotone, right-continuous and $lim_{x \rightarrow - \infty} F(x) = 0$, then there exists exactly one measure $\mu$ on $(\mathbb R, \mathcal B(\mathbb R))$ such that $F = F_{\mu}$.

How can I show this statement?

Comment: You could start with what you asked for: uniqueness.

Comment: For existence: Set $\mu((a,b]) := F(b)-F(a)$ for $a\le b$ and show that $\mu$ is a pre-measure on the ring $\{(a,b] : a\le b\}$.